# How to set width of btn using auto layout and adjust it for iPhone 6 plus?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, ios8, iphone-6-plus

I am learning swift and trying to do a test calculator project to get a feel of Xcode 6 and iOS 8.

I have set the storyboard as wCompact,hAny. This is my how the view is :

[image]

- Left padding for AC button is 16.
- Left padding for rest of the buttons is 8. so the distance between each button is 8.
- Top padding for all buttons is 8.
- Height of all buttons is 30.

I have set the width of each button as following :

[image]

I have calculated constant as

```
constant = 16(AC left padding) + 8(distance between AC and "(") + 8(distance between "(" and ")") + 8(distance between "(" and Adv) + 16(Adv right padding)
constant = 56

and multiplier = 4(total number of buttons)
```

This way i am trying to keep the width of all the four buttons same. It's working great for iPhone 4/4S, 5/5S and 6.

[image]

But when i run on iPhone 6 plus the buttons are pushed to right like this :

[image]

Could this be related to the different ppi, 401, of iPhone 6 plus or down sampling of UI view that happens in iPhone 6 plus?

Any help will be great.

**Update 1 : In response to answer posted by @Mundi**

I have tried adding left padding to the "Adv" button but then the button is being pushed to left and it overlaps with the ")" button. It then looks like following :

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Add a minimum spacing constraint to the right for your rightmost button, or right-align with the fields above.

Comment: Then the rightmost button is pushed to left and 3rd, 4th button from left overlap each other. I have updated the the question with the corresponding image.

Comment: Obviously, you will  have to make either the width of the buttons flexible or the distance between them.

Comment: that is what i am trying to do. I want to make the width of the buttons flexible and keep the distance between them intact. Its working till iPhone 6. Any idea how to achieve this for iPhone 6 plus.